# How to find total price of invoice by summing each line of the invoice?

Tags: sql, sum

How can I get the total price of each invoice from a table that has multiple invoices? For example,

[image]

Comment: NOTE: this table was created by joining the customer, invoice, and line tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use sum and group by
eg if you need  sum for each inv_number  you can use the sum of the product between  line_units and line_price eg:

```
select inv_number, sum(line_units*line_price) as total
from my_table 
group by inv_number
```

and if your my_table is a joi  result you can

```
select t.inv_number, sum(t.line_units*t.line_price) as total
from (
 your select  ........... 
) t
group by t.inv_number
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps immensely  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CUS_FNAME
    ,CUS_FNAME
    ,SUM(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) TOTALPRICE
FROM 
    dbo.Invoices
GROUP BY
    CUS_FNAME,CUS_LNAME
```

Pretty simple, just used group by. Hope this helps!